# Oracle outer join on 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, outer-join

If I have two tables (A and B) that are joined on col 'id' and i want to get all records from A regardless of a corresponding record in B, I know I can do:

```
select * from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id;
```

Now I have 3 tables A,B,C
A is joined to B and B is joined to C.
I want all records from A irrespective of whether there is a record in B or C.
So should I write
`select * from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id and` (....now what do I write here)
even using old syntax, I am stuck:
`select * from A,B,C where A.id = B.id(+) and B.id1 = C.id1(+)`(Somehow this does not seem right)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * 
from A 
   left outer join B on A.id = B.id
   left outer join C on C.id = B.id
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you tell me how to write in old syntax (just for my knowledge)?

Comment: Also, should the second condition not be: left outer join C on B.id = C.id?

Comment: @Kaushik: don't use the old syntax. `B.id = C.id` is absolutely identical to `C.id = B.id` there is no difference whatsoever in which order you write an `=` condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sir, can you please help me that how do I get this query in `CodeIgniter`? any suggestion.